# Scope value disappears from UI after adding custom filter

Tags: angularjs

I have UI which looks something like this

```
Country [Click for Asia] [Click for Europe]
Japan
China
Italy

Country [Click for Asia] [Click for Europe]
India
Korea
France
```

When i click on Click of Asia or Click of Europe I expect to see the results of Asian or European countries [myFilter gets activated]

On click action looks like this. As you see i send "this" value as i want changes to be reflected only on a subset

```
<button data-style="slide-right" data-spinner-color=#006b24 ng-click="Activate(this,'Asia')>
```

Function

```
$scope.Activate = function (repeatScope,filter) {
         console.log(repeatScope);

         temp = [];
         angular.forEach(repeatScope.value, function (value,key) {
                if (repeatScope.value[key].continent == filter) {
                    temp.push(repeatScope.value[key]);
                }
            });
         repeatScope.myfilter = temp;

         console.log(repeatScope.myfilter);

        };
```

repeatScope.myfilter prints the the value as expected but the UI becomes completely blank.

Please let me know what's the error here

Comment: With angular an scope inheritance it will be almost impossible to see where the value is lost in the `scope hell` without having the original HTML and JS

Comment: Why are you passing 'this' into your function, shouldn't you have all the variables on your $scope in your controller already?

Comment: Is `repeatScope` supposed to be the same as `$scope`?

Comment: You need to include more of your code for this to be possible to address. Include your HTML as well.